# Why does acetate aldol with Evans auxiliary give almost no diasteroselectivity?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aldol-reaction, stereoselectivity

The following acetate aldol reaction gives no diasteroselectivity:

[image: Evans' acetate aldol showing little diastereoselectity]

Because I don't know what the basis of above statement is (I heard it in a lecture and read it on some internet web pages), I expect the two products are formed as a racemic mixture.

For the related propionate aldol we can draw two (considering R of aldehyde to always be equatorial) possible transition states:

[image: Transition states for Evans' aldol reactions]

The question is why we don't get good selectivity if we compare the acetate aldol with the same transition states for the propionate aldol?

As a side-note: in practice chlorine is used instead of Me to obtain good selectivity and the chlorine will be eliminated finally by use of Zn/AcOH.

Comment: Quick reaction :) But still it's amide not ester.

Comment: The Evans auxiliary is an imide.

Comment: Yeah, is it hydrolyzed later?  Btw your question is very narrow - it lowers chances for good answer

Comment: With $\ce{LiOH/H2O2/NaHSO3}$ it can be hydrolized to a $\beta$-hydroxy-carboxylic acid.

Comment: Do you have any sources for the transition states and the reactions itself? What are we talking about when we say failed selectivity, ist it racemic or only slight discrimination?

Comment: Aldol reactions with Evans aldol can be described with this Zimmerman-Traxler transition state (I have no resources than those of the lecture). I expect people mean racemic when they say "no selectivity", otherwise they would need to say "bad selectivity" if they mean slight discrimination.

Comment: You might find something useful [here](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic93502.files/Lectures_and_Handouts/28-Aldol-2.pdf)

Comment: @ron I haven't found an explanation in your link. Unfortunately I've not enough time now to look into all the "Other Useful References" listed there.

Comment: I bet if you build a cyclohexane-chair model you'll find that when the methyl group is present it strongly favors the cyclohexane conformation with the methyl equatorial (there won't be much of the other chair where the methyl would be axial).  When you change Me to H you lose that conformational preference and both stereoisomers can now be formed, one from each of the 2 possible chairs.

Comment: I don't think so, because (in my knowledge) it's the isopropyle groupe of the imidazolidinon (conformation determined by dipole minimization) and not the methyl which primatily determines from which side the aldehyde can attack. But I agree with you exchange of Me by H would give (very slight?) discrimination. May the question is to which extent the i-Pr and to which the Me dictates from which side the attack can happen.

Answer (score 8):

#### 1. The acetate aldol reaction

Before looking at selective variants, its worth pointing out what an acetate aldol is.

An acetate aldol (below), is the simplest kind of aldol in which the β-hydroxyketone product has no methyl group at the α-position to the carbonyl. This is in contrast to the (more usual?) propionate aldol reaction in which the α-position contains a methyl group (as is common in polyketides).

> [image]
>
> **Source**: *Modern methods in stereoselective aldol reactions,* Wiley.

Early studies into acetate aldols quickly established that it was far harder to set a **single stereo centre** than to introduce two stereocentres concomitantly. This was due to the cyclic transition states involved (Zimmerman-Traxler model) in which the methyl group bound to the enolate (in the propionate aldol) exhibits a level of control which isn't present in the acetate aldol.

#### 2. The Evans' auxiliary and its applications in the aldol reaction

Whilst many aldol reactions exhibit **diastereoselectivity**, they show no inherent **enantioselectivity**. Several approaches were developed to fix this including chiral auxiliaries and chiral reagents. One of the most 'famous' of these was Dave Evans' oxazolidinone auxiliaries.

These are used to gain enantioselectivity, but can also be used to override substrate control to get the desired product.

> [image]
>
> **Source**: Dave Evans' CHEM206 Lecture notes, Harvard

With propionate aldols, this works excellently (see above), giving d.r.'s well in excess of 20:1 (about the maximum NMR can detect), with a 300:1 d.r. being quoted by Evans'. With acetate aldols however, the selectivity drops down to 1:1.

Let us consider the TS for the propionate aldol.

> [image]
>
> **Source**: Dave Evans' CHEM206 Lecture notes, Harvard

Evans' himself discusses the two diastereomeric TS structures. The favoured on top we now rationalise by opposing the dipoles between the auxiliary and enolate.

An alternate reason for why the disfavoured TS was disfavoured was provided by computational work, in which it appears that the methyl group in the propionate system clashes with the auxiliary.

> [image]
>
> **Source**: Evans' and Houk.

By disfavouring one TS (Steric clash) and favouring another (opposing dipoles), we gain good diastereoselectivity.

When the α-methyl group is taken away (as it is in the acetate aldol), we lose the unfavourable interaction (no more steric clash between the enolate and the auxiliary) leaving us only with the favourable dipole-dipole minimisation.

There is perhaps also another argument here which is that without the α-methyl group the enolate is **considerably** smaller, meaning that the TS doesn't even need to be quite so organised in order for the reaction to proceed.

#### 3. Selective acetate aldols

As a closing point, switching from boron --> tin, and using a slightly modified auxiliary does allow for selectivity to be achieved.

> [image]
>
> **Source**: Unknown

This works because the sulfur and tin remain coordinated throughout the reaction rather than with the Evans' chemistry where the oxygen points into space to allow the dipoles to oppose. This results in a much more ordered TS.

Comment: The dipole-dipole interaction will remain the same for both acetate and propanoate enolates, and this would lead to some stereoselectivity in both cases, but the steric interaction is diminished for acetate, hence there is no stereoselectivity. This makes me conclude that the steric factor is the only important factor here, am I right? By the way, great question and answer.